# How to set value in the textblock based on other textboxes and query in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Right now I have such form:[image]

The aim, that I'm trying to reach, is to open another form based on `block_id` value by pressing button. And it works. But block_id value in textblock should be based on three other values in the form: `N_table`, `target_table` and `source_table`. In the attached picture can be seen block_id's textblock form options.  Source values for that textblock is query with name `s2`, and I tried to limit `block_id` value by setting filter here this way:

```
([s2].[N_table]=[Form1].[Список0]) AND 
([s2].[target_table]=[Form1].[Список2]) AND 
([s2].[source_table]=[Form1].[Список4])
```

There `s2` is the query name, `Form1` is the name of current form, `Список0` and so on is the just list of values for first 3 textboxes. However that doesn't work at all. So `block_id` is independent. That is wrong here and how it can be fixed?

PS I'm really sorry for not english language in the attached picture, I can't change the language. And I tried to deal with the problem by using `Event Processing` macros but failed.

Comment: update the pic with English version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't read your language, but it looks if the **FilterOnLoad** property is set to **No**. Change it to **yes**, then it should work.